# Importing QML Document Directories

Tags: qt, import, qml, qmake, rcc

I want to import my custom QML type MyType from subdirectory mytypes into my main.qml file. Which is also in the same directory with the mytypes folder. I used this documentation page as reference.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-directoryimports.html

I use it as follows:

```
import "mytypes"

MyType {

}
```

In code, MyType is recognized and highlighted as usual. However, when I run the application, I get the following error:

```
qrc:/main.qml:5:1:  "mytypes": no such directory
```

And my .qrc file looks like that:

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>main.qml</file>
</qresource>
<qresource prefix="/mytypes">
    <file>mytypes/MyType.qml</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

So where is the  error? Should I also make some changes in the .pro file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The qrc file

```
<qresource prefix="/mytypes">
    <file>mytypes/MyType.qml</file>
</qresource>
```

says `mytypes/MyType.qml` is under the prefix `/mytypes`. Therefore, the import statement in `main.qml` should include that prefix:

```
import "mytypes/mytypes"

MyType { }
```

---

Or, remove `/mytypes` prefix and move `mytypes/MyType.qml` under `/` prefix in qrc file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>mytypes/MyType.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

and `main.qml` can import the type directly:

```
import "mytypes"

MyType { }
```